# filter files in file picker

Tags: jsf, primefaces, html-input

How do I made it such that, without using flash or java applets, to filter files in the OS file picker using jsf (or primefaces)?
I'm talking something that can be done like with:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept

If I try to do like exemplified here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadDnd.jsf
The file picker does not filter.

I don't care for compatibility for browsers that does not support this HTML attribute.

I'm interested in having the browser to output the correct HTML right from the start. If I can do it with plain HTML, I want to do it with plain HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without javascript:

You can do it by implementing a custom render for that component.. but It's not worth it...

#### With javascript,

As the multiple file upload component is a [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin,
you can use the accept attribute of the file input field to limit the file type selection, 
The accept attribute is [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_accept.asp) in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 6.

An example limiting files to images using jQuery (Assuming your fileUpload widgetVar is fileUploadWV):

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  // setTimeout waits till the widgetVar is ready!
  setTimeout(PF('fileUploadWV').jq.find('input:file').attr('accept', 'image/*'), 2000);
 });
</script>
```

*See more:*

- [Intro to PrimeFaces widgetVar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)
- [How to restrict the file selection dialog to show only specific file types?](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-restrict-the-file-selection-dialog-to-show-only-specific-file-types)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The @accept of input works on firefox, chrome, opera and IE10+. Its full functionality, though, is limited to chrome and firefox, IIRC.  
BTW, why do I have to use javascript for that?!?! Why can't I just output the HTML for the browser?

Comment: Well I didn't test it personally, I had it tested on chrome and it's working fine... the supporting is mentioned in the plugin website .. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks for trying... I'll update the question too so that I can be specific that I'm interested in the HTML only.

Comment: You can do it by implementing a custom render for that component.. but It's not worth it... I have updated the answer with the full javascript usage.. just place it in your xhtml :)

Comment: Really? A custom renderer for something so simple? those guys are crazy... Every time I need something simple that exists in HTML5 the only answer is "custom render". Thanks, it's not your problem but I get mad when I'm forced to use this framework when I could use the simpler HTML+CSS+jsp.

Comment: I still wonder why would I need to wait 2s... I'd just place an event and when it fires, I do it. In this case I'd place the event to DOMContentLoaded... IIRC, in jQuery it's .ready()

Comment: You are right, it's kinda strange, but this component somehow takes time to be ready by the widgetVar reference ...

Comment: Isn't there an event or something like it when it is ready? What is that ready anyway, isn't it all HTML? The input element is there from the very start (a well made HTML, for a change). Why can't I just do it as soon as the HTML is fully loaded (DOMContentLoaded)? Any resource that can help me understanding that?